# bash script not working properly

Tags: bash, scripting

I just started to learn some basic bash scripting and fail to reproduce the simples of scripts.

I have got the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "/home/test/*"; do
  echo  test
done
```

This should print test for each file in the directory /home/test/. There are many files and subfolder in that dir, but it still does print "test" only once.

Whats the issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` will not glob inside of quotes.  You need to write it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "/home/test/"*; do
  echo  test
done
```

[3.1.2 Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting)

Comment: great, that worked. How do I exclude subdirectories? echo test for each file, but not subdirs?

Comment: You only need the quotes if there are spaces in the directory names.

Comment: @ARAGATO: You could probably use `find` for something like that, if you have issues that may warrant another question.  @Marco: True but there is no harm in over quoting, especially for a beginner.  You will run into more issues without quotes than you will with quotes.